# how to copy an animation from one mask to another mask

Tags: animation-nodes, dopesheet, splines

I Have an animated mask. I can copy the splines to create a new second mask of it very easily, but the animation does not appear on the dopesheet of the second mask.

Is there a way to copy this animation from one mask to another? or maybe an add-on that you could suggest?

Thanks in advance.

[image]